# Pairwise Comparison of Rows in R

Tags: r, comparison

I have a dataset that contains results for many tests across many samples. The samples are replicated within the dataset. I would like to compare the test results between replicates within each group of replicated samples. I thought it might be easiest to first split my data frame by the SampleID so that I have a list of data frames, one data frame for each SampleID. There could be 2, 3, 4, or even 5 replicates of a sample so the number of unique combinations of rows to compare for each sample group is not the same. I have the logic that I am thinking laid out below. I want to run a function on the list of data frames and output the match results. The function would compare unique sets of 2 rows within each group of replicated samples and return values of "Match", "Mismatch", or NA (if one or both values for a test is missing). It would also return the count of tests that overlapped between the 2 compared replicates, the number of matches, and the number of mismatches. Lastly, it would include a column where the sample names are pasted together with their row numbers so I know which two samples were compared (ex. Sample1.1_Sample1.2). Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
    #Input data structure
    data = as.data.frame(cbind(rbind("Sample1","Sample1","Sample2","Sample2","Sample2"),rbind("A","A","C","C","C"), rbind("A","T","C","C","C"), 
                 rbind("A",NA,"C","C","C"), rbind("A","A","C","C","C"), rbind("A","T","C","C",NA), rbind("A","A","C","C","C"),
                 rbind("A","A","C","C","C"), rbind("A",NA,"C","T","T"), rbind("A","A","C","C","C"), rbind("A","A","C","C","C")))

    colnames(data) = c("SampleID", "Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4","Test5","Test6","Test7","Test8","Test9","Test10")
    data 

    data.split = split(data, data$SampleID)


    ##Row comparison function
    #Input is a list of data frames. Each data frame contains results for replicates of the same sample.
    RowCompare = function(x){
      rowcount = nrow(x)
      ##ifelse(rowcount==2,
        ##compare row 1 to row 2
          ##paste sample names being compared together
          ##how many non-NA values overlap, keep value
          ##of those that overlap, how many match, keep value
          ##of those that overlap, how many do not match, keep value
      #ifelse(rowcount==3,
          ##compare row 1 to row 2
            ##paste sample names being compared together
            ##how many non-NA values overlap, keep value
            ##of those that overlap, how many match, keep value
            ##of those that overlap, how many do not match, keep value
          ##compare row 1 to row 3
            ##paste sample names being compared together
            ##how many non-NA values overlap, keep value
            ##of those that overlap, how many match, keep value
            ##of those that overlap, how many do not match, keep value
          ##compare row 2 to row 3
            ##paste sample names being compared together
            ##how many non-NA values overlap, keep value
            ##of those that overlap, how many match, keep value
            ##of those that overlap, how many do not match, keep value
      return(results)
    }

    #Output is a list of data frames - one for sample name
    out = lapply(names(data.split), function(x) RowCompare(data.split[[x]])) 

    #Row bind the list of data frames back together to one large data frame
    out.merge = do.call(rbind.data.frame, out) 
    head(out.merge)

    #Desired output
    out.merge = as.data.frame(cbind(rbind("Sample1.1_Sample1.2","Sample2.1_Sample2.2","Sample2.1_Sample2.3","Sample2.2_Sample2.3"),rbind("Match","Match","Match","Match"), 
                      rbind("Mismatch","Match","Match","Match"), rbind(NA,"Match","Match","Match"), rbind("Match","Match","Match","Match"), rbind("Mismatch","Match",NA,NA), 
                      rbind("Match","Match","Match","Match"), rbind("Match","Match","Match","Match"), rbind(NA,"Mismatch","Mismatch","Match"), rbind("Match","Match","Match","Match"), 
                      rbind("Match","Match","Match","Match"), rbind(8,10,9,9), rbind(6,9,8,8), rbind(2,1,1,1)))

    colnames(out.merge) = c("SampleID", "Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4","Test5","Test6","Test7","Test8","Test9","Test10", "Num_Overlap", "Num_Match","Num_Mismatch")
    out.merge
```

One thing I did see on another post that I thought might be useful is the line below which would create a data frame of unique row combinations that could then be used to define which rows to compare in each group of replicated samples. Not sure how to implement it though.

```
    t(combn(nrow(data),2))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with `t(combn(nrow(data),2))`.  See below for how I would do it.

```
testCols <- which(grepl("^Test\\d+",colnames(data)))

TestsCompare=function(x,y){
  ##how many non-NA values overlap
  overlaps <- sum(!is.na(x) & !is.na(y))
  ##of those that overlap, how many match
  matches <- sum(x==y, na.rm=T)
  ##of those that overlap, how many do not match
  non_matches <- overlaps - matches # complement of matches
  c(overlaps,matches,non_matches)
}

RowCompare= function(x){
  comp <- NULL
  pairs <- t(combn(nrow(x),2))
  for(i in 1:nrow(pairs)){
    row_a <- pairs[i,1]
    row_b <- pairs[i,2]
    a_tests <- x[row_a,testCols]
    b_tests <- x[row_b,testCols]
    comp <- rbind(comp, c(row_a, row_b, TestsCompare(a_tests, b_tests)))
  }
  colnames(comp) <- c("row_a","row_b","overlaps","matches","non_matches")
  return(comp)
}

out = lapply(data.split, RowCompare)
```

Produces:

```
> out
$Sample1
     row_a row_b overlaps matches non_matches
[1,]     1     2        8       6           2

$Sample2
     row_a row_b overlaps matches non_matches
[1,]     1     2       10       9           1
[2,]     1     3        9       8           1
[3,]     2     3        9       9           0
```

Comment: Thank you! Generally I think this works well and will get me started, but I would like to also know exactly which tests are the matches and non-matches. See my `out.merge` example. Is there a way to include this information?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 How would you parallel process these functions?

Comment: @wake_wake that's a question unto itself, but see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36035435/2573061) for a related question