# Subset of data table when computing in parallel

Tags: r, foreach, split, data.table

I'm trying to run a parallel computation with data.table. I have a big data set, and I'd like to work with every group of subjects independently and in parallel.

Let: DataP is a big data set: ID, x1, x2, x3, group

My code is:

```
# Data preparations
# I split an index (indx) because data split takes a lot of time with my data.
setkey(DataP ,SplitKey_f)
indx<-split(seq(nrow(DataP )),DataP $group)
l<-length(unique(DataP$group))

library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
cl<-makeCluster(8)
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(i=1:l, .combine = rbind) %dopar% { 
  library(data.table)
  Psubset<-DataP [,indx[[i]]]
  # some transformations on the data
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

The above doesn't work because foreach with parallel computing cannot execute the line:

Psubset<-DataP [,indx[[i]]]).

However, %do% instead of %dopar% works good (but a lot of time).

How can I fix the problem - fast sub-setting a data.table within a parallel loop?

Comment: `data.table` doesn't really have support for parallel computations. It's by-reference mechanisms don't really play well with parallel computations. It your reason for parallelization is that you call a function *within*  data.table that is very time consuming, you are better served by not using data.table. However, that doesn't seem to be the case for you ("some transformations on the data"). I suspect that your actual problem is that you don't really leverage data.table well. (I also note that you don't assign the `foreach` loop, which indicates that you haven't understood `foreach` well.)

Comment: You should describe (including a reproducible example) what you are actually trying to achieve, so that people can suggest improvements to your data.table code without the need of parallelization.

Comment: This could be of interest to you https://github.com/jangorecki/big.data.table

Comment: Why is it `Psubset<-DataP [,indx[[i]]]` instead of `Psubset<-DataP[indx[[i]],]`? You're trying to split over rows not columns, right?

Comment: There is a new `split.data.table` method coming soon, it is faster than `split` you've currently used. Lack of reproducible example prevents many people from posting an answer, be aware of it. You can use `big.data.table` if your operations on chunks can be proceed independently, follow the link from David's comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment from @Roland above nonwithstanding, I've actually found that this type of approach can be very effective, and I've used it to parallelize millions of computations over millions of rows on a 40-core EC2 instance.

The first thing I would do is ensure that your key is set to the column you'll be using as an index for subsetting.  Your index is a list of arrays, and that's a little different than I usually do it, but it should still work.

Try the following:

```
out <- 
  foreach(i = indx, .packages = c('data.table'), .combine = data.table::rbind ) %dopar% {
    Psubset<-DataP[i,]
    # do some operations on Psubset
  }
```

Or if for some reason `combine` isn't working or needs additional arguments you can do it after the fact.

```
out_list <- 
  foreach(i = indx, .packages = c('data.table') ) %dopar% {
    Psubset<-DataP[i,]
    # do some operations on Psubset
    )
  }
out <- rbindlist(outlist) #, fill=TRUE, etc.
```

If that doesn't work I would take a look at the index so that it works more like:

```
out <- 
  foreach(i = 1:max_indx, .packages = c('data.table'), .combine = data.table::rbind ) %dopar% {
    Psubset<-DataP[indx==i,]
    # do some operations on Psubset
  }
```

But without a reproducible example it's hard to know which one would work best.