# In R - fastest way pairwise comparing character strings on similarity

Tags: r, string, dataframe, string-comparison, stringdist

I'm looking for a way to speed up the following approach. Any pointers are very welcome. Where are the bottlenecks?

Say I have the following `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(names=c("A ADAM", "S BEAN", "A APPLE", "J BOND", "J BOND"), 
                      v1=c("Test_a", "Test_b", "Test_a", "Test_b", "Test_b"), 
                      v2=c("Test_c", "Test_c", "Test_d", "Test_d", "Test_d"))
```

I want to compare each pair of rows in `df` on their JaroWinkler similarity.

With some help of others ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486831/pairwise-comparison-of-rows-in-r)), I've been able to construct this code:

```
#columns to compare 
testCols <- c("names", "v1", "v2")

#compare pairs
RowCompare= function(x){
 comp <- NULL
 pairs <- t(combn(nrow(x),2))
 for(i in 1:nrow(pairs)){
   row_a <- pairs[i,1]
   row_b <- pairs[i,2]
   a_tests <- x[row_a,testCols]
   b_tests <- x[row_b,testCols]
 comp <- rbind(comp, c(row_a, row_b, TestsCompare(a_tests, b_tests)))
 }

colnames(comp) <- c("row_a","row_b","names_j","v1_j","v2_j")
return(comp)
}

#define TestsCompare
TestsCompare=function(x,y){
names_j <- stringdist(x$names, y$names, method = "jw")
v1_j <-stringdist(x$v1, y$v1, method = "jw")
v2_j <-stringdist(x$v2, y$v2, method = "jw")
c(names_j,v1_j, v2_j)
}
```

This generates the correct output:

```
output = as.data.frame(RowCompare(df))

> output
   row_a row_b   names_j      v1_j      v2_j
1      1     2 0.4444444 0.1111111 0.0000000
2      1     3 0.3571429 0.0000000 0.1111111
3      1     4 0.4444444 0.1111111 0.1111111
4      1     5 0.4444444 0.1111111 0.1111111  
5      2     3 0.4603175 0.1111111 0.1111111
6      2     4 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.1111111
7      2     5 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.1111111
8      3     4 0.5634921 0.1111111 0.0000000
9      3     5 0.5634921 0.1111111 0.0000000
10     4     5 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

However, my real data.frame has 8 million observations and I make 17 comparisons. To run this code takes days...

I am looking for ways to speed up this process:

- Should I use matrices instead of data.frames?
- How to parallelize this process?
- Vectorize?

Comment: Honestly, it's a lot simpler to compare each column independently: `lapply(df, stringdist::stringdistmatrix, method = 'jw')`. [stringdist has some parallelization built-in, as well,](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringdist/versions/0.9.4.4/topics/stringdist-parallelization) though you'll need to make sure everything is configured.

Comment: To extend that approach to get back to what you have, `library(tidyverse); df %>% map(stringdist::stringdistmatrix, method = 'jw') %>% map_df(broom::tidy, .id = 'var') %>% spread(var, distance)`. I also recently ran across [multidplyr](http://www.business-science.io/code-tools/2016/12/18/multidplyr.html), though there are lots of ways to parallelize.

Comment: @alistaire I like this! Thank you. Is there a way to differentiate between different methods? Say, an exact string match on v1 and a 'soundex' match on v2. Is that possible with `stringdist::stringdistmatrix` ?

Comment: Sure, just use `purrr::map2` (in base, `Map`) and supply a vector of methods, e.g. `map2(df, c('soundex', 'jw', 'jw'), ~stringdist::stringdistmatrix(.x, method = .y))`

Comment: Great!! How can we structure the output into a data.frame? The output from `purrr::map2` are lists, right?

Comment: Yep. The resulting structure is exactly the same as that from the `lapply` in my first comment, so you can add it to a pipeline just like `map` my second.

Comment: @alistaire If I add `map2(df, c('soundex', 'jw', 'jw'), ~stringdist::stringdistmatrix(.x, method = .y))` to the pipeline, I get an error that 'Value column 'distance' does not exist in input'. Where is the value `distance` created?

Comment: By `broom::tidy.dist`. Altogether, it would be `map2(df, c('soundex', 'jw', 'jw'), ~stringdist::stringdistmatrix(.x, method = .y)) %>% map_df(broom::tidy, .id = 'var') %>% spread(var, distance)`, which works fine for me.

Comment: You may be interested in packages such as RecordLinkage. See "Statistical Matching and Record Linkage" section in "OfficialStatistics" CRAN task view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you iterate over the variables you want to check, you can make a distance matrix for each with `stringdist::stringdistmatrix`. Using a form of `lapply` or `purrr::map` will return a list of distance matrices (one for each column), which you can in turn iterate over to cal `broom::tidy`, which will turn them into nicely formatted data.frames. If you use `purrr::map_df` and use its `.id` parameter, the results will be coerced into one big data.frame, and the name of each list element will be added as a new column so you can keep them straight. The resulting data.frame will be in long form, so if you want it to match the results above, reshape with `tidyr::spread`.

If, as you mentioned in the comments, you want to use different methods for different variables, iterate in parallel with `map2` or `Map`.

Altogether,

```
library(tidyverse)

map2(df, c('soundex', 'jw', 'jw'), ~stringdist::stringdistmatrix(.x, method = .y)) %>% 
    map_df(broom::tidy, .id = 'var') %>% 
    spread(var, distance)

##    item1 item2 names        v1        v2
## 1      2     1     1 0.1111111 0.0000000
## 2      3     1     1 0.0000000 0.1111111
## 3      3     2     1 0.1111111 0.1111111
## 4      4     1     1 0.1111111 0.1111111
## 5      4     2     1 0.0000000 0.1111111
## 6      4     3     1 0.1111111 0.0000000
## 7      5     1     1 0.1111111 0.1111111
## 8      5     2     1 0.0000000 0.1111111
## 9      5     3     1 0.1111111 0.0000000
## 10     5     4     0 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Note that while `choose(5, 2)` returns 10 observations, `choose(8000000, 2)` returns 3.2e+13 (32 *trillion*) observations, so for practical purposes, even though this will work much more quickly than your existing code (and `stringdistmatrix` does some parallelization when possible), the data will get prohibitively big unless you are only working on subsets.

Comment: Right. Memory becomes an issue. What subset approach would you take that makes sure each pair in the original data.frame gets compared?

Comment: You can't, unless you've got some spectacular hardware. The next step forward depends a lot on the particulars. Maybe there's a small handful of strings you care whether each observation matches; maybe you're looking for inherent groupings and should use some form of cluster analysis. Some browsing over at [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) may help lead you down a fruitful path.